# Type mismatch using DLookup to return/evaluate a global variable name(string) to RHS of assignment to .BackColor(long) (Possible type casting issue?)

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

## Problem:

I am getting a type mismatch error when using DLookup to return a global variable name(string) to the RHS of assignment to the .BackColor(long) property.

**How do you pass a variable name(`string`/`text`) through a record look-up (`DLookup`) and evaluate its contents on the RHS of an expression.**

*"give me the value of the variable whose name matches this string"*

### Debug:

I have tried various versions of escaping (with `"` or `'`), evaluating (with `Eval()`), type casting (with `Clng` and `Cstr`), and checking proper scope with no success. See "*Debug Immediate Output*" section

From the code below, specifically this line: `Me.cboSelect.BackColor = DLookup("[BackColor]", "myTable", "[myTableID] = " & Me.cboSelect.value)`

If `Me.cboSelect.value=1` the code breaks with a type mismatch.

If `Me.cboSelect.value=2` then the code works perfectly.

### Situation:

I would like to define some common colors that I can store (as global variable names instead of the obscure number codes) in my tables along with the data that needs to be highlighted. I don't want to use conditional formatting because every form requires using the GUI to setup the conditionals and I prefer to have VBA to do the highlighting along with data entry in forms (this also leads to a more consistent user interface.

Essentially I would like to be able to store a global variable name along with my data. Even if there is a better solution for doing conditional formatting in VBA I would still like to know how to pass a variable name through a record look-up and evaluate its contents.

### Code:

## myTABLE

```
myTableID(autoNum)  mainData     Backcolor(text)
1                   "str1"       glngOrange
2                   "str2"       52479
```

## Constants (VBA Module)

```
Global glngOrange As Long
Public Sub initGlobals()
    glngOrange = RGB(255, 204, 0) ' 52479
End Sub
```

## Form (VBA Module)

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Call initGlobals
End Sub

Private Sub cboSelect_LostFocus()
    Debug.Print "A) Check that global is in scope. glngOrange = ", glngOrange
    Debug.Print "B) Dlookup ", DLookup("[BackColor]", "myTable", "[myTableID] = " & Me.cboSelect.value)
    Debug.Print "C) Type ", TypeName(DLookup("[BackColor]", "myTable", "[myTableID] = " & Me.cboSelect.value))

    'The following line works if .value=2, fails if .value=1
    Me.cboSelect.BackColor = DLookup("[BackColor]", "myTable", "[myTableID] = " & Me.cboSelect.value)
End Sub
```

## Debug Immediate Output

```
A) Check that global is in scope. glngOrange = 52479 
B) Dlookup       glngOrange
C) Type          String
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are attempting something like *"give me the value of the variable whose name matches this string"*.

Having been down that road, I suggest you consider a different approach.

Instead of a set of global variables, use a `Scripting.Dictionary` which has your names as its keys and the corresponding numbers as its values.

```vb
Dim dct As Object
Set dct = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
dct.Add "glngOrange", 52479
' and so forth ...

' later you can retrieve the number associated with a given key ...
Debug.Print dct("glngOrange")
```

Comment: I really like the `Scripting.Dictionary` idea. However, I am still unable to store the desired color (via the dct("glngOrange") call) inside the table. I replaced 'glngOrange' in **myTable.BackColor** and I still get the type mismatch. Is there a way to escape the `dct()` call so that I can use it on the right hand side (RHS) of an assignment to `Me.cboSelection.BackColor`?

Comment: If your table is designed and loaded such that your `DLookup` always returns a string which corresponds to one of the dictionary keys, maybe this will suit: `Me.cboSelect.BackColor = dct(DLookup("[BackColor]", "myTable", "[myTableID] = " & Me.cboSelect.value))`

Comment: It Worked! I setup **myTable** with unique dictionary keys and followed your assignment line above; it is so obvious now! BTW, I created my `Scripting.Dictionary` object in a global namespace and did the key>value pairing inside my `initGlobals` subroutine.

Answer (score 1):

HansUp has already given a sleek solution to your problem. I personally would edit the **myTable** by adding another field for actual long number representing the colour name. This will give you an opportunity to remotely control your colour codes (in case if the tables are linked tables).

Just to answer your last question how to turn string/text into vba code. One way would be to use the "Microsoft Visual Basic For Applications Extensibility library" to construct and execute(.Run) strings into vba code.

read more here: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Are you recommending that I make a **colorDefinition** `table` that consists of the `ColorID` (autoNum), `colorName`(string), & `colorNumCode` (long)? I added the `mainData` column to illustrate that, in my example, **myTable** is actually storing other data and the `BackColor` column is more of a property. I think a **colorDefinition** `table` might work if I set a `1-to-1` relationship with **myTable** (after adding a new column `ColorID`). Let me play with it; will I need to do nested DLookup values? the first would return `ColorID` and the second would return `colorNumCode`?

Comment: @EnTrABl it depends on how you want to mange it. I prefer theme colours so i manage them in a table rather than hardcoded functions. This allows me add/edit/delete themes remotely (backend server)

Comment: That makes sense; by adding the settings in a separate table you can modify the theme without having to update the back-end VBA code. In my case, this is a single-user (me) application that I am prototyping locally so I can afford to hard code functions for now. I will definitely keep your suggestions in my pocket for the future since your approach makes sense for production applications.